# Inserting record to mysql table, via sqlalchemy , with autoinc throws FlushError

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a row for a table which has `auto_increment` as well as some foreign keys. All the foreign keys exist. But it throws error.

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance Stock at 0x9cf062c has a
>   NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the
>   database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that
>   the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated
>   values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an
>   inappropriate time, such as within a load() event.

Even insertion of record via MySQL, by copy-paste SQL produced by `echo=True`, is executing.

**Stock Class**

```
class Stock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Stock'

    Code = Column('Code',String(8),primary_key=True)
    Symbol = Column('Symbol',String(128))
    ListingName = Column('ListingName',String(256))
    ListingDate = Column('ListingDate',DateTime())
    RecordAddedDate = Column('RecordAddedDate',DateTime())

    HomeCountry = Column('HomeCountry',ForeignKey('Country.Code'))
    PrimaryExchange = Column('PrimaryExchange',ForeignKey('Exchange.Code'))
    BaseCurrency = Column('BaseCurrency',ForeignKey('Currency.Code'))
    InstrumentType = Column('InstrumentType',ForeignKey('Instrument.InstrumentType'))
```

**Record insertion**

```
Engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://user:pass@host/db',echo=True)
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
SessionObj = Session()

NewStock = Stock()
NewStock.InstrumentType = 'Stock'
NewStock.Symbol = 'MSFT'
NewStock.ListingName = 'Microsoft'
NewStock.HomeCountry = 'IN'
NewStock.PrimaryExchange = 'NSEOI'
NewStock.BaseCurrency = 'INR'
NewStock.ListingDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
NewStock.RecordAddedDate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

print NewStock

SessionObj.add(NewStock)
SessionObj.flush()

print NewStock.Code
```

Comment: Hint: what happens when you go to the MySQL shell and type `SHOW CREATE TABLE Stock` does it show `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 1):

Add [`autoincrement=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#column-table-metadata-api) to your column.

Comment: It is not in your code; perhaps you should post the complete code you are using.

Comment: reckon `autoincrement` is optional, i didn't have it in original code but tried it after googling. updated with more code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had the column type as String, after converting to Integer worked fine.